# RegEx specific numeric pattern in Excel VBS

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I do not have much RegEx experience and need advice to create a specific Pattern in Excel VBA.

The Pattern I want to match on to validate a `Userform` field is: `nnnnnn.nnn.nn` where n is a 0-9 digit.

My code looks like this but Reg.Test always returns false.

```
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With RegEx
        .Pattern = "/d/d/d/d/d/d\./d/d/d\./d/d"
    End With
    If RegEx.Test(txtProjectNumber.Value) = False Then
        txtProjectNumber.SetFocus
        bolAllDataOK = False
    End If
```

Comment: Did you succeed Steve? If so, please accept/and or upvote any of the answers below that solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. You need to match the whole contents of the textbox (I assume) so use anchors (^ and $).

Your slashes were the wrong way round. Also you can use quantifiers to simplify the pattern.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim RegEx As Object, bolAllDataOK As Boolean
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With RegEx
        .Pattern = "^\d{6}\.\d{3}\.\d{2}$"
    End With
    If Not RegEx.Test(txtProjectNumber.Value) Then
        txtProjectNumber.SetFocus
        bolAllDataOK = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

VBA got it's own build-in alternative called [`Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) operator. So besides the fact you made an error with forward slashes instead of backslashes (as @SJR rightfully mentioned), you should have a look at something like:

```
If txtProjectNumber.Value Like "######.###.##" Then
```

Where `#` stands for any single digit (0–9). Though not as versatile as using regular expressions, it seems to do the trick for you. That way you won't have to use any external reference nor extra object.

Comment: Yep, much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the Help!

Comment: @stevemontague. You are welcome. Please consider to choose an answer to accept by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. Either one is fine, but that way you'll be closing the question.